# Proof of $g(A∪B)=g(A)∪g(B)$, for sets $A⊆X$ and $B⊆X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that $g(A∪B)=g(A)∪g(B)$ for sets $A⊆X$ and $B⊆X$, where $g : X → Y$ is a function. I'm quite new to set theory, and was wondering what would be a good way of structuring a proof. My intuition is that you would start with $g(A)∪g(B)$, and take arbitrary elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ and use them to show $g(A∪B)$. However, I don't really see how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to write down the definition.

For $y\in g(A\cup B)$ there exists $x\in A\cup B$ such that $g(x)=y$. Since $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ we see that $g(x)\in g(A)$ or $g(x)\in g (B)$, i.e., $g(x)=y\in g(A)\cup g(B)$.

Since $y$ is arbitrary, this shows that $g(A\cup B)\subset g(A)\cup g(B)$.

The converse is similar.

Comment: I believe it is useless to ask why I've got a downvote for this answer...

Comment: You're right, about that. I've had a lot of criticism but I've never yet had an explanation from a down-voter .

Answer (score 0):

An element is in the image of the union of many sets iff it is the image of an element of the union iff it is an image of an element of one of the sets being unioned iff it is in the image of one of the sets being unioned iff it is in the union of the images of the sets being unioned.

Comment: @amWhy You mad bro?

Comment: Of course not, sis! Chill...